# How to compute V(N|N+S=2) for a given tableau?

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem state:

> Let N denote the number of accidents occurring during one month on the
>   northbound side of a highway and let S denote the number occurring on
>   the southbound side. Suppose that N and S are jointly distributed as
>   indicated in the table.

```
N\S            0           1           2       3 or more
  0           0.4         0.06       *0.10*     0.04
  1           0.10       *0.18*       0.08      0.03
  2          *0.12*       0.06        0.05      0.02
  3 or more   0.05        0.04        0.02      0.01
              0.67        0.34        0.25
```

I compute the sum of the colum with

```
S=0 is => 0.67

S=1 is => 0.34

S=2 IS => 0.25
```

Then by def. I have

```
V(N|N+S=2)=E(N^2|N+S=2)-E(N|N+S=2)
```

And,

P(N=n|N+S=2)=P(N=n,S=2-n)/P(S=n-2)

Then for n=0,1,2 I have:

```
P(N=0|N+S=2)=0.10/0.25=2/5

P(N=1|N+S=2)=0.18/0.34=9/17

P(N=2|N+S=2)=0.12/0.67=12/67
```

Finaly I can compute:

```
E(N|N+S=2)=0*2/5+1*9/17+2*12/67=(1011/1139)

E(N^2|N+S=2)=0*2/5+1*9/17+4*12/67=1.2458
```

*Variance asked:*

```
V(N|N+S=2)=E(N^2|N+S=2)-E(N|N+S=2)=0.3582
```

**My promblem is:** That I can't find my error, because the book said the answer is **0.5475** but ny number doesn't much. If someone can't tell me where is my error I will be happy. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `V(N|N+S=2)=E(N^2|N+S=2)-E(N|N+S=2)^2`, not `V(N|N+S=2)=E(N^2|N+S=2)-E(N|N+S=2)`.

Answer (score 2):

the way u found the denominator is wrong. P(N+S=2) is equal to the different combinations where N+S=2, so P(N+S=2)=0.4. so use that and the rest of your method together will give u the right answer. 
thus E(X)=2(0.12/0.4) + 1(0.18/40)+0 and E(X^2)=(2^2)(0.12/0.4)+(1^2)(0.18/0.4)
1.65-1.05^2=0.5475

Comment: Indeed  It should be emphasised that $\mathsf P(N=n\mid N+S=2)=\frac{\mathsf P(N=n,S=2-n)}{\mathsf P(\mathbf{N+S=2})}$, **not** $\frac{\mathsf P(N=n,S=2-n)}{\mathsf P(S=2-n)}$ as the OP had.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Good answers are sometimes ignored because they are not formatted properly